How to send firebase cloud message to multiple device tokens at a time using kreait/firebase-php
I am trying to send using the following code, but I am getting the error "Operation is not implemented, or supported, or enabled."
$users = [
    ['registration_token' => "eUr2Gyu0R-WD2giKqQuBHO:APA91bE97YKaBcc0-nckfDcGfF1U0olmkDxomvjM-HM-fNfy9yl1IwBvOPOxvzTATktfIz8GU-daCwr4HB3qYBtwAdvpaJ839cLaJ32XW0NVLToJ07dfJkxTMGhWe-fVAvRw314AOsP6"],
    // ...more tokens
];

$messages = [];

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $messages[] = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $user['registration_token'])
        ->withNotification([
            'title' => "Tittle...",
            'body' => "Message",
        ]);
}

$messaging = (new Factory())
    ->withServiceAccount('firebase_cloud_messaging.json')
    ->createMessaging();

$sendReport = $messaging->sendAll($messages);

echo 'Successful sends: ' . $sendReport->successes()->count() . PHP_EOL;
print_r($sendReport->failures());```


The sendMulticast() message is a convenient method to send one message to multiple devices.
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\CloudMessage;

$message = CloudMessage::new(); // Any instance of Kreait\Messaging\Message
$deviceTokens = ['...', '...' /* ... */];

/** @var Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\MulticastSendReport $sendReport **/
$sendReport = $messaging->sendMulticast($message, $deviceTokens);


For more information related to this issue refer to this  documentation.
